Detailed steps to run pact4s example
I am trying to run the pact4s example share here: https://github.com/jbwheatley/pact4s However there is no detailed steps shared. Can someone help?

Can you expand on what you're trying to do? Consumer side? Provider? What framework are you using? You can look at the examples in the project. Feel free to open an issue or even a PR to improve the onboarding of the README isn't clear enough.

I'm no scala expert, but from what I can see:

There is some comment on examples here: https://github.com/jbwheatley/pact4s?tab=readme-ov-file#running-the-examples
The CI build seems to use the testExamples command: https://github.com/jbwheatley/pact4s/blob/main/.github/workflows/pr-build.yml#L17

So my guess would be to clone the project and run something like sbt testExamples.
Feel free to raise an issue and/or PR to the project to make it easier for the next person :)
